# How to access a directives value from template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a minimum validation directive. How can I access my directives value from the template? limitChartsForm.min does not work.

Template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" min="1" max="10" [(ngModel)]="_limit"
                            #limitChartsForm="ngModel">

({{limitChartsForm.min}}-{{limitChartsForm.max}})
```

Validator:

```
    @Directive({
    selector: '[min]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MinValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class MinValidator implements Validator {
    constructor( @Attribute('min') public params: string) {

    }

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        let value = parseInt(control.value);

        let min: number = parseInt(this.params);

        if (min == NaN)
            return;

        if (value == NaN || value < min)
            return { min: false }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the ="ngModel" ? Did you try it without it?

Comment: Without the direct accessing of #limitChartsForm-Properties (like #limitChartsForm.errors) will not work anymore.

Comment: I think you should add to the directive (in the meta): exportAs: 'min-validator' and then add #limiteChartsMin='min-validator' then you can access limitChartsMin.min, you'll have to repeat the same for max